# Amazon FireTV Stick: Forced 640x480 resolution

Tags: android, adb, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I have a FireTV Stick that is plugged into a DVI monitor with an HDMI-to-DVI adapter. Apparently the stick can't detect the monitor's resolution properly. It outputs a non-changeable 640x480 resolution. When I try to change it in the settings, the FireTV Stick lets me know that no other resolution is supported.

[This source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/fire-tv/help/firetv-stick-5-0-5-0-forced-output-t3353469) suggests to change the setting using ADB. Apparently there used to be a setting called `secure amazon_settings_hdmi_resid` that is no longer available (calling `settings get secure amazon_settings_hdmi_resid` returns `null`). Changing `wm size` seemingly changes the input resolution that then gets downscaled to 640x480.

While all [standard settings are well-documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html), additional Amazon properties are nowhere to be found. Is there a way to query all settings? My device is not rooted and running software version 5.2.1.2.

All help to changing the resolution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried holding `rewind` and `up` on the remote for a few seconds... I believe that gives you an option to cycle through any resolution it thinks it's capable of (though if your DVI adapter isn't HDCP capable it may simple lock at SD)

Comment: I tried. A popup opens for a blink of an eye and then closes itself again. Do you think getting a different adapter could solve the problem? The screen is HDCP compatible but that probably doesn't matter when using an adapter.

Comment: yeah, you might need a different adapter. I had similar problems with an HDMI adapter for routing audio to an optical output, first one I got was cheap and didn't seem to respond correctly to HDCP but the replacement (about $10 more) has been rock solid

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Sam. The DVI monitor broke and was replaced by a smart TV so I didn't look into it any further.

Answer (score 0):

There are three kind of system settings. You can get them like this:

- `adb shell settings list global`
- `adb shell settings list secure`
- `adb shell settings list system`

Comment: That does not work for me. It doesn't seem to accept anything other than get, put and delete.

Comment: What Android version is it on?

Comment: The Fire Stick's (FireOS) software version is 5.2.1.2.